# Slow spatial comparison when using cross join

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm using U-SQL to select all objects which are inside one or more of the shapes. The code works but is really slow. Is there some way to make it more performant?

```
@rs1 =
    SELECT DISTINCT aisdata.imo,
                    portshape.unlocode
    FROM @lsaisdata AS aisdata
         CROSS JOIN
             @portsshape AS portshape
    WHERE Geometry.STMPolyFromText(new SqlChars(portshape.shape.Replace("Z", "").ToCharArray()), 0).STContains(Geometry.Point(aisdata.lon, aisdata.lat, 0)).IsTrue;
```

Added more information about my issue:

- I've registered Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll and SqlServerSpatial130.dll to be able to use spatial functions in U-SQL
- I'm running my job in Data Lake Analytics using two AUs. Initially I used 10 AUs, but the Diagnostics tab stated that the job was 8 AUs over-allocated and max useful AUs was 2.
- The job takes about 27 minutes to run with the UDT code below and the cross join takes almost all of this time
- The input is one csv file (66 Mb) and one wkt file (2.4 Mb)
- I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Azure Data Lake Tools v2.2.5000.0
- I tried encapsulating some of the spatial code in UDTs and that improved the performance to 27 minutes:

`@rs1 =`
    `SELECT DISTINCT aisdata.imo,`
    `portshape.unlocode`
    `FROM @lsaisdata AS aisdata`
    `CROSS JOIN`
    `@portsshape AS portshape` 
    `WHERE portshape.geoShape.GeoObject.STContains(SpatialUSQLApp.CustomFunctions.GetGeoPoint(aisdata.lon, aisdata.lat).GeoObject).IsTrue;`

Comment: A bit more detail please! Are you running it locally? How long is "slow"? How much data? What about as a job in Azure with 200 compute nodes? Still slow? What version of Visual Studio? What version of Data Lake Tools do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

First, a `CROSS JOIN` will always explode your data to an NxM matrix. Depending on the number of rows this may either make it very expensive and possibly hard to estimate correct degree of parallelism.

Secondly, I assume that the Spatial join you do is an expensive operation. For example, if you use SQL Server 2012's spatial capabilities (2016 has native implementations of the type that may be a bit faster), I assume you probably get similar performance behavior. Most of the time you need a spatial index to get better performance. Now U-SQL does not support spatial indices, but you probably could approximate the same behavior by using an abstraction (like tessellation of the objects and determining if they overlap), to provide a faster pre-filter/join before you then test the condition to weed out the false positives.